# Is spectroscopic analysis of flowing air sensitive to the amount of matter or the flux?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, spectroscopy, models, sensor

I would like to like to go deeper in understanding the analytical and physical behaviour of air quality analysers. AQ analysers are merely based on spectroscopy (absorbance, fluorescence, chemiluminescence) and deal with a compressible fluid that continuously flows through the analytical bench.

I first thought that such analysers were sensitive to the amount of matter ($\mathrm{mol}$) because the technique relies on molecular properties that are measured using light (eg. Beer Lambert). But now I am considering the fact that it might be sensitive to flux ($\mathrm{mol\cdot s^{-1}\cdot m^{-2}}$) instead, because we need to take into account the fact that matter flows through the detection cell, it is not a batch lab experiment, it is a continuous measurement. Is this point correct? Is spectroscopic analysis of an air sample flowing continuously is sensitive to amount of matter or to the flux of this quantity?

Comment: @David Z, Thank you for the edit, I am not a native speaker. May I ask you why have you withdrawn my reference request?

Comment: It's better to just ask the question you want. People will link to references anyway, if they think the references are relevant, whether you ask for them or not.